# Unity 3D rendering issues on iPad Mini

Tags: ipad, user-interface, unity-game-engine, rendering, vuforia

So, my team and I are experiencing an interesting issue. We're developing an app for the iPad mini. When I build the app for an iPad 4 or 2, it looks like this:

[image]
[image]

This is the way it's supposed to look. However, when my client receives the build on testflight on his iPad mini 4 (or even when he builds it himself from xCode), he sees the pictures below, and the app is extremely laggy and broken. The AR Camera we're using (Vuforia is in the project, but these issues persist even when all AR stuff is disabled) won't work. It looks like it could be some kind of rendering problem, but why it would happen on his iPad, and not any of mine, completely mystifies me. Can anyone explain this?

The specs for [my friend's iPad are as such](http://pastebin.com/NbhGT9j7) (he lives thousands of miles away, and there's no chance I can inspect the iPad personally).

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you use to create the UI?

Comment: @Max Yankov unity ui.

Comment: @MaxYankov Unity UI. Why?

Comment: Please give us more info? Like maybe your code?

Comment: @blackmorningus Well, I'm not exactly sure what code you'd like to see -- none of this is happening in any one place. It's the whole app that's like this, I think.